# disabled button in listview duplicate in every 3 times

Tags: android, listview

Hi I'm new android developer and I have one question.
I have one custom listview and it has 5 items. 
The item consist of 5 textview, 1 button.
textviews are everything fine but button is strange....

my code(about button) flow is

1. Check a deliveryltemPosition.order_taken_str's value.
2. if deliveryltemPosition.order_taken_str is 2 , complete_btn is disabled.

but It is duplicate in every 3 items...
only second button value is 2, but also 6th button is disabled.

-> (button_able) (button_disable) (button_able) (button_able) (button_able) (button_disable) (button_able)

how to fix it?

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){
          View itemView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_selected_delivery_item, parent, false);

               final Deliveryltem deliveryltemPosition = epicerieDelivery.selectedDeliveryItem.get(position);

                icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_delivery_img);
                name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_name);
                phone_tx = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_phone);
                addrress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_address);
                memo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_memo);
                street_add = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_street_address);
                complete_btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_complete_btn);

                if(deliveryltemPosition.order_taken_str.equals("2")){
                    Log.d("1/28","order_taken : " + deliveryltemPosition.order_taken_str);
                    complete_btn.setEnabled(false);
                }
                phone_tx.setText(deliveryltemPosition.recipient_phonenum);
                address=deliveryltemPosition.recipient_address;
                addrress.setText(deliveryltemPosition.recipient_address);
                memo.setText(deliveryltemPosition.recipient_memo);

                if(deliveryltemPosition.address_street!=null){
                    street_add.setText(deliveryltemPosition.address_street);
                }

                shipping_time = deliveryltemPosition.shipping_time;
                name_st = name.getText().toString();
                phone_st = phone_tx.getText().toString();

                complete_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position , 0);
                    try{

                        order_seq = deliveryltemPosition.order_seq;
                        position_sms = position;
                        Deliveryltem deliveryltemPosition1 = epicerieDelivery.selectedDeliveryItem.get(position);
                        String name = deliveryltemPosition1.recipient_name;
                        String phone = deliveryltemPosition1.recipient_phonenum;
                        AlertDialog dialog = createdialogBox_finish(name, phone, position);
                        dialog.show();
                    }catch (Exception e){

                   }
          }
            });
            return itemView;


        }else{
            itemView = convertView;

            if(epicerieDelivery.selectedDeliveryItem.size() != 0){

                final Deliveryltem deliveryltemPosition = epicerieDelivery.selectedDeliveryItem.get(position);
                icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_delivery_img);
                name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_name);
                phone_tx = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_phone);
                addrress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_address);
                memo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_memo);
                street_add = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_street_address);
                complete_btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_complete_btn);

                if(deliveryltemPosition.order_taken_str.equals("2")){
                    Log.d("1/28","order_taken : " + deliveryltemPosition.order_taken_str);
                    complete_btn.setEnabled(false);
                }

                phone_tx.setText(deliveryltemPosition.recipient_phonenum);

                address=deliveryltemPosition.recipient_address;
                addrress.setText(deliveryltemPosition.recipient_address);
                memo.setText(deliveryltemPosition.recipient_memo);

                if(deliveryltemPosition.address_street!=null){
                    street_add.setText(deliveryltemPosition.address_street);
                }

                shipping_time = deliveryltemPosition.shipping_time;
                name_st = name.getText().toString();
                phone_st = phone_tx.getText().toString();


                complete_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position , 0);
                        try{
                            order_seq = deliveryltemPosition.order_seq;
                            position_sms = position;
                            Deliveryltem deliveryltemPosition1 = epicerieDelivery.selectedDeliveryItem.get(position);
                            String name = deliveryltemPosition1.recipient_name;
                            String phone = deliveryltemPosition1.recipient_phonenum;

                            AlertDialog dialog = createdialogBox_finish(name, phone, position);
                            dialog.show();
                        }catch (Exception e){

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "다시 눌러주세요!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }



                    }
                });

            }
            return convertView;
        }
 }
```

Comment: what's the value of that variable in DeliveryItem

Comment: try to use viewholder pattern, sample : http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (deliveryltemPosition.order_taken_str.equals("2")){
    complete_btn.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    complete_btn.setEnabled(true);
}
```